# Oracle ORDER BY Multiple Columns Not Working

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I'm trying to use Oracle's ORDER BY statement on multiple columns but only one column is being sorted. My query is

```
SELECT s.STDLASTNAME, s.STDFIRSTNAME, s.STDGPA
FROM Student s
ORDER BY 
    s.STDGPA DESC,
    s.STDLASTNAME,
    s.STDFIRSTNAME;
```

This is my result:

```
STDLASTNAME STDFIRSTNAME    STDGPA
COLAN       CRISTOPHER      4
PILGRIM     WILLIAM         3.8
DODGE       MARIAH          3.6
KENDALL     CANDY           3.5
DODGE       TESS            3.3
ESTRADA     JOE             3.2
WELLS       HOMER           3
KENDALL     WALLY           2.8
NORBERT     BOB             2.7
MORALES     ROBERTO         2.5
BRAZZI      LUKE            2.2
```

But I expected to get:

```
STDLASTNAME STDFIRSTNAME    STDGPA
BRAZZI      LUKE            2.2
COLAN       CRISTOPHER      4
DODGE       MARIAH          3.6
DODGE       TESS            3.3
ESTRADA     JOE             3.2
KENDALL     CANDY           3.5
KENDALL     WALLY           2.8
MORALES     ROBERTO         2.5
NORBERT     BOB             2.7
PILGRIM     WILLIAM         3.8
WELLS       HOMER           3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by the last name, then it should be the first key in the `order by`:

```
order by stdlastname, stdfirstname, stdgpa desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
  SELECT s.STDLASTNAME, s.STDFIRSTNAME, s.STDGPA
 FROM Student s
    ORDER BY 
    s.STDLASTNAME
    s.STDFIRSTNAME, s.STDGPA
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you wrote:

```
ORDER BY 
    s.STDGPA DESC,      --> (A)
    s.STDLASTNAME,      --> (B)
    s.STDFIRSTNAME;     --> (C)
```

It means:

- First, sort the result by values in `s.stdgpa` column in descending order (A).
- If it turns out that two (or more) rows share the same `s.stdgpa` value (none of them do in your example), then sort those rows by `s.stdlastname` in ascending order (B)
- if two (or more) rows share the same `s.stdlastname` value (it is the case with  `DODGE` and `KENDALL`), then sort those rows by `s.stdfirstname` in ascending order (C) (so, for DODGEs, MARIAH comes first, TESS next)

Apparently, you want to sort the result by last name, then first name, then (probably) `STDGPA` (in descending order), so that would be what people above have already said:

```
ORDER BY 
    s.STDLASTNAME,
    s.STDFIRSTNAME,
    s.STDGPA DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try either

`ORDER BY s.STDLASTNAME, s.STDFIRSTNAME`

or

`ORDER BY s.STDLASTNAME, s.STDGPA DESC`

to get the desired result.